# Relationship between Azure SAS allowed services and allowed resource types

Tags: azure

I am reading the Azure SAS documentation (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/fileservices/constructing-a-service-sas) and I am confused with the relationship between allowed resource Types and Azure services.

If I go to storage account -> shared access signature, the first thing I have to select is Allowed Services (Blob, file, queue, table). Then the Allowed resource types (Service, Container and Object).

Now a Blob service has container in it, but a file, queue or table does not have containers in them. So why is Container option provided in allowed resource type for file, queue and table service?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> Now a Blob service has container in it, but a file, queue or table
>   does not have containers in them. So why is Container option provided
>   in allowed resource type for file, queue and table service?

Don't think of a `container` mentioned there as `blob container`. Think of it as something that will have child elements (objects in this case).

In context of blobs, `container` will refer to `blob container` which will contain `blobs`.

In context of file service, `container` will refer to `share` which will contain `files` & `directories`.

In context of table service, `container` will refer to `table` which will contain `entities`.

In context of queue service, `container` will refer to `queue` which will contain `messages`.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification Gaurav

Answer (score 16):

As far as I know, the resource type, you could regard as below:

- Service (s): Access to service-level APIs (e.g., Get/Set Service Properties, Get Service Stats, List Containers/Queues/Tables/Shares)
- Container (c): Access to container-level APIs (e.g., Create/Delete Container, Create/Delete Queue, Create/Delete Table, Create/Delete Share, List Blobs/Files and Directories)
- Object (o): Access to object-level APIs for blobs, queue messages, table entities, and files(e.g. Put Blob, Query Entity, Get Messages, Create File, etc.)

Comment: Thanks Brando Zhang.